# Does using Crystal Reports in Asp.net for WebUser Requires installation?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

If im a web developer and some of the feature of my site is display a crystal report , Does a Web user in the outside world should install any Dlls to see the report ?

I know that in WinForm he should. but i dont know about web approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is No. Crystal Report's Web interface will produce dynamic content of Html/Css/JavaScript.